# decompose a string into array of int without loop java

Tags: java

I want to decompose a string into Int array using JAVA,

i don't want a solution that iterates each element of array

than typecast to integer.

is there any shortcut for this ?

Comment: I am not sure I am following, Do you have a `String[]` and you want to make it an `int[]`? Or is it `String` to `int[]`? Or do you want an `Integer[]` as a result? Please be more specific what *exactly* are you trying to achieve

Comment: Which kind of string you have? Which manner you ant to decompose?

Comment: Why the restriction on a loop? Doing this by looping is most likely the most straightforward solution.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a homework question and Yogesh is meant to be learning about recursion.

Comment: even if you find some api method to do this..internally it will do the looping

Comment: @NickHolt: He'll learn much more from the answers :)

Comment: This question is very vague.  You need to show your work.  What have you tried?  What code have you written?  Otherwise it is a candidate for closure.

Answer (score 2):

No loops (visible)... but was it really worth it?

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import org.hamcrest.collection.IsArrayContainingInOrder;
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;

@Test
public void testDecompose() {
    final String input = "1,2,3,4";
    Integer arr [] = Iterables.toArray(Iterables.transform(Splitter.on(",").split(input), new Function<String,Integer>(){
        @Override public Integer apply(String input) {
            return Integer.parseInt(input);
        }}), Integer.class);
    assertThat(arr, IsArrayContainingInOrder.arrayContaining(1,2,3,4));
}
```

To get `Collection<Integer>` or `List<Integer>` it's even simpler - as you'll be getting `Iterable<Integer>` from the `transform`:

```
@Test
public void testDecompose() {
    final String input = "1,2,3,4";
    List<Integer> l = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.transform(Splitter.on(",").split(input), new Function<String,Integer>(){
        @Override public Integer apply(String input) {
            return Integer.parseInt(input);
        }}));
    assertThat(l, IsCollectionContaining.hasItems(1,2,3,4));
}
```

Comment: "but was it really worth it?" No ;) But +1 for the effort ;)  Incidently I guess this is still looping internally just doing the parseInt as part of the `Spliter` loop?

Answer (score 2):

Not a single loop in sight... but then as @Nick pointed out... you probably need to learn a bit about recursion:

```
private static void getNumbers(List<String> asList, List<Integer> myList) {
    if (asList.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    } else {
        String remove = asList.remove(0);
        myList.add(Integer.parseInt(remove));
        getNumbers(asList, myList);
    }

}
```

And the calling code:

```
    String numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
    List<String> inputList = new ArrayList<String>();
    inputList.addAll(Arrays.asList(numbers.split(",")));
    List<Integer> outputList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    getNumbers(inputList, outputList);

    System.out.println(outputList);
```

Comment: Curses! Beat me mid way through answering. +1

Comment: +1 Same as above! But at least I've managed to post another solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You gonna have to iterate on each character of your String to achieve that:

```
String str = "1234";
int[] array = new int[str.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    array[i] = Character.digit(str.charAt(i), 10);
    // or
    // array[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
}
```

EDIT

If you really want no loop:

```
String str = "123,456,789";
String[] arr = str.split(",");

ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

list.add(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]));
list.add(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
list.add(Integer.parseInt(arr[2]));
```

But you gonna have to know the number of Integer you have first, if you don't you need a loop.

Comment: as written in my Question i don't need any loop.
solution like 
String str = "123,456,789";
List<Integer> list = str.split(",");

Comment: @yogeshprajapati Can you give us the reason for that?

Comment: @ talnicolas reason for that is i have lacs of entries so i dont want loop for each.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware - no.  There's no simple way of doing that as the String is just a char[] which only maps to integers through ascii. You could get an array of strings assuming you have a delimiter then refer to each index of the array of String with a function which converts the String into an int, but frankly you are making it a lot harder for yourself...

e.g.

```
String myEncodedInts = "7,14,12,9,3";
String[] myIntsAsStrings = myEncodedInts.split(",");
//...
int someReferenceAtSomeLaterPoint = Integer.parseInt(myIntsAsStrings[myReferenceIndex]);
```

But there's no way (that I know of) of just converting the String[] to an int[] that doesn't just hide the loop inside some other method...

Comment: I want all element in List<Integer>.

Comment: @yogeshprajapati So you don't want an int array but a List, please correct your question.

Comment: It kind of doesn't matter - there's still no way to do it without a loop.  Perhaps if you explained why you don't want a loop then we could work out someway to avoid your reason for not wanting a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the comment Yogesh has added to @Matt Fellows answer:

'*I want all element in List. – yogesh prajapati*'

Write a custom implementation of List that's backed by the array and does the type conversion when the items are accessed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public toInts(String[] strings, int[] ints, int start) {
    if (start > strings.length - 2) {
        return;
    }
    ints[start] = Integer.parseInt(strings[start]);
    toInts(string, ints, start+1);
}
...
int[] ints = new int[3];
String[] strings = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};
toInts(strings, ints, 0);
```

There, no iterations.

But seriously folks, any solution is going to have some form of iteration (or recursion) at some point.