# Decompose a String into Array of Long or List of Long without Loop in JAVA

Tags: java

I want to decompose a String array into Long array or List.
I don't want to use Loop.

Is there any Java Method to do this.

Comment: So the array contains string representations of `long`s? You need to be a lot more specific and include both desired in-/output and your attempt at solving it yourself.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993916/decompose-a-string-into-array-of-int-without-loop-java) question asked recently.

Comment: @milkplusvellocet: No, the other question is about parsing a String into an array of ints. This question is about "converting" a String array into a Long array (without defining the "converting" part)

Comment: Perhaps OP should clarify what they mean. This popped up a very short time after a very similarly worded question which is why it stood out to me as a duplicate. Anyway the essence of the question (not wanting to use a loop) is the same.

Comment: @milkplusvellocet maybe a bunch of people taking an online exam or something

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no O(1) operation to "convert" a `String[]` (with numeric strings) to a `long[]`. It will always be O(n), if the loop visible or hidden in some thirdparty method.

If you don't want to "see" the loop, simply implement a method

```
Long[] pseudoOneStepConversion(numbers);
```

and implement

```
privat Long[] pseudoOneStepConversion(String[] numbers) {
  Long[] result = new long[numbers.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
     result[i] = Long.parseLong(numbers[i]);
  return result;
}
```

---

We can do it recursively too - it is still O(n), less performant and doesn't look like a loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Long> target = new ArrayList<Long>();
    copy(new String[]{"1", "2", "3"}, target, 0);
    System.out.println(target);
}

private static void copy(String[] source, List<Long> target, int index) {
    if (index == source.length)
        return;
    target.add(Long.parseLong(source[index]));
    copy(source, target, index+1);
}
```

*Note - because I start getting downvotes for the recursion example: It is purely academic and not inteded for use in production code - thought, that was clear ;)*

Comment: I think this is not about time complexity, but about code conciseness. As I read it, OP needs something like `map` in functional programming (I think Guava has something like that).

Comment: Unforunately in Java, loops are the most concise/readable form in many of these cases. Perhaps closures will change this in Java 8.

Comment: Down voting, because recursion performs much worse then plain loop in Java. There are optimizations in the JVM JIT compilers targeting loops, but currently there is no optimization for tail recursion in the JVM (unlike Lisp and few other VMs).

Comment: Err, Eugene, please read question and answer carefully: (a) Lalit asked for a solution *without* loops and (b) I already warned, that the recursion is not advisable ("less performant").

Answer (score 14):

Simplified Eugene answer with Guava library. Since Guava 16.0.

```
List<Long> longList = Lists.transform(Arrays.asList(stringArray), Longs.stringConverter());
```

**Update:** Solution with Java 8, without 3th party libraries:

```
List<Long> longList = Stream.of(stringArray).map(Long::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is the best answer if you are looking to minimize no of lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

With a little help of [3rd party libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained?tm=6) you can avoid coding loops in your own code, but there would be a loop somewhere under the hood. For example:

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(stringArray);
List<Long> longList = Lists.transform(stringList, new Function<String, Long>() {
   public Long apply(String s) {
      return Long.valueOf(s);
   }
});
```

Classes [Lists](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html) and [Function](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) are from Guava library.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to do this without a loop (even if you don't code explicitly a loop, the method you will call will use one), unless you now the number of `long` values contained in the `String` and add them manually to your `List`.

Comment: Of course there is: Tail recursion. When it comes down to the processor level, *all control structures are goto*. Also, I don't think it would be a problem for OP if the helper function uses a loop, as long as he doesn't have to polute his/her code with repetitive iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is Guavas [Lists.transform](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) function.

```
String[] stringArray = {"1999", "20000"};
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(stringArray);
List<Long> longList = Lists.transform(stringList, 
                                      new Function<String, Long>() {
                                              Long apply(String value) {
                                                return Long.valueOf(value);
                                      }
                       });
```

Note: Guava will of course have to do a loop to achieve this, but there are no loops in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Split String value with comma and Converting String Array to Wrapper Long Array / Primitive long array using Java 8.

```
String values = "2846, 4514, 8495, 4587, 5772, 3813, 6947, 3186";
Long[] longArray = Arrays.stream(values.split(","))
                                .map(String::trim)
                                .map(Long::valueOf)
                                .toArray(Long[]::new);//Converting String array to Long array
long[] longPrimitiveArray = Arrays.stream(values.split(","))
                                        .map(String::trim)
                                        .mapToLong(Long::valueOf)
                                        .toArray();//Converting String array to long array
```