# How to split a string into an integer array?

Tags: java

How can we split a string into an integer array without using loops?

**For example:**

If I have a string `"12345"` and I  wanted to be converted to int array `[1,2,3,4,5]`  without using loop. I know how to do it that way. Is there any built-in function that java provides that splits and converts into desired data type?

Comment: At least show how you would do it with loops

Comment: It's called streams BTW, the built in concept you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235401/split-string-into-array-of-character-strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decompose a String into Array of Long or List of Long without Loop in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994180/decompose-a-string-into-array-of-long-or-list-of-long-without-loop-in-java)

Comment: "Is there any built-in function that java provides" - _Yes_

Comment: toCharArray() would help

Comment: Thanks I was looking for doing that with streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Java 8 you could use a **[Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)**:

> "A sequence of elements supporting sequential and parallel aggregate
>   operations."

Observe:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String numbersString = "12345";

    int[] numbersIntArray = Stream.of(numbersString.split("")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray(); 

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbersIntArray)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 You can do using Arrays util also.

```
String string = "12345";
int[] ints= Arrays.asList(string.split("")).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion.

```
public class Test {

    static List<Integer> integerArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static int strLength;
    static String s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        s = "12345";
        strLength = s.length();

        recursiveMe(0);

        System.out.println(integerArray.toString());
    }

    public static void recursiveMe(int n) {
        if (n < strLength) {
            integerArray.add(n, Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(n))));
            recursiveMe(n + 1);
        }
    }

}
```