# Convert String[] to long[]

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, split

How can one convert a `String[]` into `long[]`?

I have a `String[] inputArray` which contains a `String` at `inputArray[31]`. I want to split that string on a specific `SPLIT_CHAR`, resulting in a `String[]` as below:

```java
String[] numbersText = inputArray[31].split(SPLIT_CHAR);
```

Now, each of the elements represents a number that I would like to parse into a `long`, so effectively receiving a `long[]`. How can I do that?

Comment: See Long.parseLong(String)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9994180/15777370

Comment: `Arrays.stream(inputArray[31].split(SPLIT_CHAR)).mapToLong(Long::parseLong).toArray()`

Comment: @QBrute Btw, there is `Pattern.compile(SPLIT_CHAR).splitAsStream(inputArray[31])...` to avoid the intermediate `String[]` array of `split`.

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation

You have to actively iterate the array after the split and parse each individual string using [`Long.parseLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)).

Note that if any of the elements is not actually a number, it will throw a `NumberFormatException`.

---

### Loop

Here is a traditional version with a simple plain loop:

```java
String[] numbersText = inputArray[31].split(SPLIT_CHAR);
long[] numbers = new long[numbersText.length];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = Long.parseLong(numbersText[i]);
}
```

---

### Stream API

And here is a modern solution using streams:

```java
long[] numbers = Pattern.compile(SPLIT_CHAR)
    .splitAsStream(inputArray[31])
    .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
    .toArray();
```

---

### Just `String[]` to `long[]`

For the sake of Q&A, here is a slightly adopted version without the split and other fuzz, as complete example:

```java
String[] numbersText = { "0", "1230", "-6", "5" };
long[] numbers = Stream.of(numbersText)
    .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
    .toArray();
```